# Dart StreamZip emit when one of the child streams emits

Tags: dart, stream

I have two datasources (a and b) which provide streams. To them new data will be added independently.
Now I want to create a stream (z) which takes these two streams and merges them to one, combining the elements.

So when "a" emits for the first time there's no value for "b" yet, nothing should happen (doesn't matter if I have to implement it or if it is integrated in the library...). Same thing when "b" emits first.

When both streams have emitted at least once, I want "z" to merge these two into each other. This works with a StreamZip.

But the problem is now, if "a" emits again, but "b" does not, StreamZip waits until "b" emits again, until itself(z) emits again.
This is by design I guess as the source shows this behavior:

```dart
// taken from: stream_zip.dart, shortened for better readability
...

    void handleData(int index, T data) {
      dataCount++;
      // subscriptions has the length 2, as I have two input streams,
      // but dataCOunt is 1, as only one source stream emitted
      if (dataCount == subscriptions.length) {
        // handle the data
        // ...
      } else {
        // don't do anything
        subscriptions[index].pause();
      }
    }
```

Is there any way how to handle this without writing the logic myself? I guess using RxDart would be one option?
Or am I using/interpreting something wrong?

Comment: Are you claiming that if `a` emits twice and `b` emits once that `z` will have 0 emissions until `b` is emitted a second time? (If so, I think that would be unexpected, and that's not what seems to be indicated by the source code.) Or do you mean that if `b` never emits again that `z` will wait forever?  If so, then what do you expect to happen instead?

Comment: Neither of those :D
I mean if `a` and `b` emit once, then after a while `b` emits again, `z` will wait until `a` also emits. So if `a` never emits again `z` will also never emit again. In this case I want `z` to emit again as soon as `b` emits, using the old value of `a` for the merging

Comment: Okay, combining the new value the *last-known* value from the other streams is an important detail that should be in your question.  That sounds pretty uncommon, and `StreamZip` definitely would not do that.

Comment: Well now as I know that zip implies that :D. But I just found that it is possible with rxdart, at least according to the docs: https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/CombineLatestStream-class.html I'll have a look into that tomorrow and report back :)